# webpack dinamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack

Пытаюсь разобраться с динамическими импортами webpack. Как это вижу я.
Допустим у меня есть роут, который в зависимости от хеша должен подключать тот или иной модуль:

```
changeRout(rout) {
    const comp = this.routes[rout] || 'error';
    import(`../components/${comp}`)
    .then(({default: comp}) => {comp.render()})
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Для этого, как пишут гуру в своих статьях я установил

```
'dynamic-import-webpack'
'@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'
```

Хз какой именно нужен, но в доках вебпака приводят @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import, в какой - то статье вычитал про dynamic-import-webpack. В общем оставил оба.
Правило для обработки js файлов в конфиге выглядит так:

```
{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {modules: false}]],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import', 'dynamic-import-webpack']
          }
        }
      }
```

Так же выставил

```
optimization: {
splitChunks: {
  chunks: 'all'
}
```

Все бы вроде хорошо, однако вебпак генерирует один общий файл с модулями и подключает его сразу на страницу, а хотелось бы что-бы чанки модулей были отдельны и подключались только при переходе по определенному роуту.
В итоге получаю 3 файла
**vendors~main.js** - здесь как я понял лежат функции всяких пагов стайл лоадеров и т.д.
**0.js** - здесь код всех модулей (а хотелось бы для каждого свой чанк)
**main.js** - ну и главный файл (точка входа)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сам `webpack` понимает синтаксис динамическогого `import()` и ему **не нужны** дополнительные инструменты/трансформеры.
Все динамическая загрузка модулей в `webpack` доступа из коробки.

Насчет `babel` и плагинов, указанных в вопросе. Зачем они вообще нужны, когда сам `webpack` умеет делать динамический импорт?
Они необходимы для самого `babel`, чтобы тот не ругался на конструкции вида `import` и не выдавал ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: <filePath>:
Support for the experimental syntax 'dynamicImport' isn't currently enabled
```

Плагин всего лишь пометит, что конструкции `import()` валидны в данном контексте и работу можно продолжать дальше.
В этом можно убедиться на примере: [на такой код](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBANiAhgEwLImQVzgUxgXhgFsNscA5RIvfAPhgG8AoGVmASyIAcQAnKABQksuStQCULNtIB0UABY4wAgeIL1QkELhkIA5gIAGAEgbCyYnAF8OEeEmQ5kh8ZOmzgiKMHkCcvXj51GE0IbRwZf0DePwC-VwBuJiskpgQUdBEcAQByIgBPAFpzXBzxBKA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.4.3&externalPlugins=) `babel` будет ругаться, но если подключить `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`, то [все будет в порядке](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBANiAhgEwLImQVzgUxgXhgFsNscA5RIvfAPhgG8AoGVmASyIAcQAnKABQksuStQCULNtIB0UABY4wAgeIL1QkELhkIA5gIAGAEgbCyYnAF8OEeEmQ5kh8ZOmzgiKMHkCcvXj51GE0IbRwZf0DePwC-VwBuJiskpgQUdBEcAQByIgBPAFpzXBzxBKA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.4.3&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-syntax-dynamic-import%407.2.0), причем исходный код и результирующий будут одинаковые, т.к. плагин всего лишь выставляет внутренний флаг `babel`, ничего не преобразуя: [исходный код плагина](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/8ca99b9f0938daa6a7d91df81e612a1a24b09d98/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/src/index.js#L9-L11).

- `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`. С ним уже должно быть понятно, еще замечу, что он упомянут в официальной документации `webpack` при описании кейса с `async/await`, которые предлагается трансформировать при помощи `babel`, и чтобы `babel` отработал корректно просят еще подключить этот плагин. Т.е. документация не говорит использовать его явно, только при необходимости.
- `dynamic-import-webpack`. Этот плагин нужен для преобразования `import()` в старый вебпаковский динамический импорт вида `require.ensure`. Уже `webpack` официально поддерживается `import()`, поэтому смысл в этом плагине на текущий момент уже нет.
  К тому же данный вид не поддерживает динамическое значение `import()`: имя модуля должно быть явно захардкорено, т.е. нельзя писать

  ```js
  // ...
  import(`./my-module${index}`)
  // ...
  ```

  необходимо вручную описать все модули

  ```js
  // ...
  import('./my-module1')
  // ...
  import('./my-module2')
  // ...
  import('./my-module3')
  // ...
  ```

  А иначе, `webpack` возьмет и все модули с префиксом `my-module` поместит в один чанк.

**Исходя из этого**:

- Если вы используете `babel`, вам нужно еще подключить плагин `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`;
- Если вы не используете `babel`, то вам не нужны никакие плагины.

Конкретно в вашем случае проблема возникает из-за плагина `dynamic-import-webpack`, если вы его удалите, все должно быть хорошо.

Также, я сделал два примера: в одном используется только `webpack`, в другом `webpack` плюс `babel`. Пример необходимо запустить командой

```
npm start
```

После открытия страницы нажмите на любую кнопку, и вы увидите, что скрипты загружаются динамически (вкладка network и консоль)
[Пример 1](https://github.com/skubarenko/stackoverflow-samples/tree/master/ru/970791/my-answer)
[Пример 2 (с babel)](https://github.com/skubarenko/stackoverflow-samples/tree/master/ru/970791/my-answer-babel)

*Из вопроса непонятно какой версией `webpack` вы пользуетесь, скорее всего последней (на текущий момент это 4).*

**Обновлено**
Если у вас webpack версии `>=4.29.0` и вы получаете ошибку вида:

```
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

То скорее всего воспроизводится этот баг: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8656

Есть пара воркэраундов:

1. Сделать downgrade вепбака до версии `4.28.4`
2. Исправить проблему с версиями пакета `acorn`, из-за которых появляется проблема.
   1) Добавить секцию `resolutions` для `package.json`:

   ```
   "resolutions": {
       "webpack/acorn": "6.1.1"
   }
   ```

   2) Установить к себе пакет `acorn` версией `6.1.1`:

   ```
   npm i --save-dev acorn@^6.1.1
   ```

   3) Запустить `npm dedupe`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако при отключении dynamic-import-webpack, я получаю ошибу:     
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (12:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: И опять же, используя функцию из приведенных Вами примеров я так же получаю один чанк со всеми модулями.

Comment: Обновил ответ, скорее всего это баг вебпака